# Can't select a view in SQL

Tags: sql

I just created a view (I use azure data studio). But I can't select * from it. It said that invalid object name (the view is already existed in database)

```
CREATE VIEW [vw_male_passenger] AS
SELECT Reservation.PNR_no AS 'PNR Number', Reservation.Aircraft_code, Passenger.Ticket_no, Passenger.Name AS 'Passenger Name', Reservation.[Status]
FROM Passenger 
INNER JOIN Reservation ON Passenger.PNR_no = Reservation.PNR_no
WHERE Passenger.Sex = 'Male';
```

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_male_passenger]
```

Comment: maybe you created the view in the wrong schema? you really should put the schema in these create statement .... `[dbo].[vw_male_passenger]` instead of just `[vw_male_passenger]`

Comment: I have checked, and the view is on the dbo schema

Comment: if the view already existed, then of course creating it should simply error. Maybe the object that "already existed" is not a view ... like a function or who knows? Have you looked at the definition of the object that exists now?

Comment: The type of the object is View

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that you can tell me all this about an object that doesn't exist. Are you sure you are in the right database when you call it? Beyond, that - I would just do a little trial and error. Drop it. Recreate it. Change the name. Run it from the navigation menu. Anything else I can think of...

Comment: I try SELECT * FROM AirlineReservation.dbo. But it just listed all the tables that existing excluded the view I created

Comment: I also check the database, and the view exists in a right place

Comment: It may exist in the right place but when you try to use it are you connected to the right database?

Comment: Yes, I only worked with only that database :(

Comment: Does it work if you create the view with a different name? Do any views work at all?

Comment: oh, I found the problem, I need to refresh the IntelliSense cache. But thank you for your question!

Comment: Whew. Good catch. Sounds like an azure studio thing then. SSMS wouldn't have that issue.